# how can we add a document using solr cloud server

Tags: java, solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

While adding a document using solr cloud server I'm getting following exception

```
60 [main] INFO org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager - Waiting for client to connect to ZooKeeper
65 [main-SendThread(jmajeed.ibsorb.com:8982)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server jmajeed.ibsorb.com/192.168.70.91:8982. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
69 [main-SendThread(jmajeed.ibsorb.com:8982)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket connection established to jmajeed.ibsorb.com/192.168.70.91:8982, initiating session
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Could not connect to ZooKeeper 192.168.70.91:8982/#/hotelcontent within 10000 ms
```

Does anybody has any idea why this is happening??

Thanks.

Comment: plz update question with your configs, solr version, solrconfig.xml, solr.xml

Comment: This issue because of our Zookeeper client connectivity .You have to mention like  solrServer = new CloudSolrServer("zookeeper client address);
       solrServer.setDefaultCollection("hotelcontent");

Answer (score 0):

Have the disturbed the default configuration of solr nodes because by default if you do not specify the port the first node in the cluster will start in 8983 port so check this first. If this is not the problem then check whether the cluster is up or not by accessing admin UI of solr cloud. Then see whether all the shards in the cluster are alive by clicking on the cloud tab.

If everything is fine and still you are facing the above problem then are you trying to access a remote solr cloud server and it is firewall issue.